# Why storm produces this error.. It keeps running for few mins and then stops

Tags: apache-storm

I am getting the following error and my worker dies
I am running storm 0.9.3
I checked in google for this but I cant find proper solution

```
2015-08-27 17:13:48 b.s.d.worker [ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-worker.java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at backtype.storm.util$touch.invoke(util.clj:563) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.6.0-2800.jar:0.9.3.2.2.6.0-2800]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__4229$exec_fn__1491__auto____4230.invoke(worker.clj:381) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.6.0-2800.jar:0.9.3.2.2.6.0-2800]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:185) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__4229$mk_worker__4306.doInvoke(worker.clj:373) [storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.6.0-2800.jar:0.9.3.2.2.6.0-2800]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$_main.invoke(worker.clj:500) [storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.6.0-2800.jar:0.9.3.2.2.6.0-2800]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker.main(Unknown Source) [storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.6.0-2800.jar:0.9.3.2.2.6.0-2800]
2015-08-27 17:13:48 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Error on initialization") java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Error on initialization")
    at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:322) [storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.6.0-2800.jar:0.9.3.2.2.6.0-2800]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__4229$mk_worker__4306.doInvoke(worker.clj:373) [storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.6.0-2800.jar:0.9.3.2.2.6.0-2800
```

Comment: This question is very specific. Obviously, Storm tries to create a new file but cannot. Why it tries to create what file is unclear. Maybe it's a bug in the system. I would recommend to ask at storm dev mailing list.

Comment: did you got a solution ?!